# Where is the Lightning tab in the developer console?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, developer-console, debugging, debug

I installed the [Salesforce Lightning Inspector Chrome Extension](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/inspector_intro.htm).

Now I want to debug my lightning component. I go to extension menu in Chrome, chose `Inspect Lightning Component` and I am getting this message:

> Please open the developer console and select the "Lightning" tab to access the Lightning inspector.

I am going over to the developer console and see not Lightning tab there:
[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wrong Developer Console. While viewing the app or in LEX, press F12 to bring up the *browser's* Developer Console. It'll be far off on the right, you might need to click the >> arrow to see it.

[image]

---

[image]